# While opening a command prompt created in D drive its path is shown as C:\Users\Abc?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, command-prompt

While opening a command prompt created in D drive its path is shown as `C:\Users\Abc ?`
I have created a command prompt in D drive of my computer which runs `Windows 7` (by typing "cmd" in a notepad and save it as commandprompt.cmd) but when opening the `commandprompt.bat` file the path shown is `"C:\Users\Abc"` (where Abc is the computer name) , but it only happens in `Windows 7.`

If I create a command prompt in `Windows XP` with the same method, opening the commandprompt.bat file shows "D" drive as path?

Is there any way to do the same in windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open My Computer, hold down shift key and right click on D:\ drive. Then select "Open command window here". This will open up a command prompt with the path of "d:\" drive.

You could also try typing this into notepad and saving as a .bat file (I haven't tried this but it's worth a shot).

**command.bat**

```
@echo off
command
command.com
```

Comment: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-open-windows-command-prompt-any-folder.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
start "" /d "d:\" cmd /k
```